# How to delete document from MongoDB using Mongoengine?

Tags: mongodb, mongoengine

How to delete document from MongoDB using Mongoengine? I'veread the API reference here:
http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html
but I can not understand what is:

```
delete(**write_concern)
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: I don't know mongoEngine, but i Think that Write concern is http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-concern/ and  `fsync: True` i think that force write on primary ( journaled )

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You can either delete an single `Document` instance by calling its delete method:

```
lunch = Food.objects.first() // Get a single 'Food' instance
lunch.delete() // Delete it!
```

Or you can delete all items matching a query like so:

```
Food.objects(type="snacks").delete()
```

Comment: You may also want to use `lunch = Food.objects.get()` if you expect one and only one document to match the query (typically request by ID).

Comment: Hey @ross, how can I now what is the status of the delete? means, how can I know it the delete ended with success of failure? anyway to retrieve that status?

Comment: @ShaiM. using try catch

Answer (score -16):

U can use the mongoshell and issue the following command:

```
db.collection.remove({your condition on documents you want to remove})
```

for example: 
From food collection you want to remove all the food which has type snacks. then you can issue the following command:

```
db.food.remove( { type : "snacks" } )
```

Comment: Isn't there any way to do it through mongoengine?